# How better I can optimize this Kusto Query to get my logs

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics

I have below query which I am running and getting logs for Azure K8s, but its takes hour to generate the logs and i am hoping there is a better way to write what i have already written. Can some Kusto experts advice here as how can I better the performance?

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where Category == 'kube-audit'
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(datetime("2022-03-26")) .. endofday(datetime("2022-03-27"))) 
| where (strlen(log_s) >= 32000
and not(log_s has "aksService") 
and not(log_s has "system:serviceaccount:crossplane-system:crossplane")    
or strlen(log_s) < 32000
| extend op = parse_json(log_s) 
| where not(tostring(op.verb) in ("list", "get", "watch"))   
| where substring(tostring(op.responseStatus.code), 0, 1) == "2"
| where not(tostring(op.requestURI) in ("/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews"))
| extend user = op.user.username
| extend decision = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.annotations)).["authorization.k8s.io/decision"])
| extend requestURI = tostring(op.requestURI)
| extend name = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.objectRef)).name)
| extend namespace = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.objectRef)).namespace)
| extend verb = tostring(op.verb)
| project TimeGenerated, SubscriptionId, ResourceId, namespace, name, requestURI, verb, decision, ['user']
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

Comment: It is very challenging improving your query without knowing anything about the data demographics, even basic stuff such as how many records in total do you have per day and how many of them does this query retrieves. I did identify one potential for improvement, assuming op.responseStatus.code starting with 2 is less common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try starting your query as follow.
Please note the additional condition at the end.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(datetime("2022-03-26")) .. endofday(datetime("2022-03-27"))) 
| where Category == 'kube-audit'
| where log_s hasprefix '"code":2'
```

I assumed that `code` is integer, in case it is string, use the following (added qualifier)

```
| where log_s has prefix '"code":"2'
```

Comment: I would write it instead as follows: | where substring(tostring(op.responseStatus.code), 0, 1) == "2" this  | where op.responseStatus.code startswith "2"

Comment: @Avnera, the idea here is to filter prior to the parsing of the json string

Comment: thanks for the answer, one thing is not clear how you can filter before parsing, I will try tomorrow but just something I didnt understood. this query is used just to get logs of my cluster. it is used once in a while. One more issue is when I increase my byte size from 32000 it times out, is that the limitation of Kusto?

Comment: (1) I'm using here an ugly trick to filter before the parsing based on a textual search. It is quite risky, since it counts on a exact match E.g. if you have a space after the colon (`"code": 2`) it's not going to work. (2) If you increase the size limitation for parsing, you parse larger documents, which takes more time, which results in timeout. No magics here.

Comment: and I read the ms docs there they say move time filter first so does it matter if I keep my filter | where TimeGenerated between .... line as the first line?

Comment: and instead of using multiple has can i use has_all? and not(log_s has ("aksService","system:serviceaccount:crossplane-system:crossplane","..") )